# Android - Java - Transmitting / Receiving Hex Values

Tags: java, android, hex

I am new to the forums, and may have posted this to the wrong one - please help a newbie.

As part of project to develop Android App, I need to be able to connect from the app to a set location, which has a small microprocessor based(unchangable) LAN interface, which will accept set commands in hex. The response is given in hex.

Using a sample socket program, which I have tried to modify (see code below), I can see (using wireshark) that the transmitted string is in ASCII, not hex, so I am sending 38 bytes, and not the 18 with the 0x prefix.

I have tried using a LONG, but the value I am trying to send is too large (see String process = '0x.....' midway through the code), and I get 'The literal 0x.... of type int is out of range.

I would appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction.

Thanks

```
// package bdn;
/* The java.net package contains the basics needed for network operations. */
import java.net.*;
/* The java.io package contains the basics needed for IO operations. */
import java.io.*;
/** The SocketClient class is a simple example of a TCP/IP Socket Client.
* For a detailed explanation of the classes in this project see
* bdn.borland.com/article/0,1410,31995,00.html
*/

public class SocketClient 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        /** Define a host server */
        String host = "192.168.1.199";
        /** Define a port */
        int port = 3376;
        int i = 0;

        StringBuffer instr = new StringBuffer();
        // String TimeStamp;
        System.out.println("SocketClient initialized to " + host + ", port " + port );

        try 
        {
            /** Obtain an address object of the server */
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(host);
            /** Establish a socket connection */
            Socket connection = new Socket(address, port);
            /** Instantiate a BufferedOutputStream object */
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            /** Instantiate an OutputStreamWriter object with the optional character
            * encoding.
            */
            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(bos, "US-ASCII");

            // TimeStamp = new java.util.Date().toString();
            String process = "0x308101000c00234C51050000000099670007";

            System.out.println("Data to be sent is " + process) ;

            /** Write across the socket connection and flush the buffer */
            osw.write(process);
            osw.flush();

            System.out.println("Data sent is " + process) ;

            /** Instantiate a BufferedInputStream object for reading
            * incoming socket streams.
            */

            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            /**Instantiate an InputStreamReader with the optional
            * character encoding.
            */

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(bis, "US-ASCII");

            /**Read the socket's InputStream and append to a StringBuffer */
            int c;
            for (i = 0; i <= 18; i++ ) 
            {
                c = isr.read() ;
                instr.append((char) c);
                System.out.println("character " + i + " value " + c);
            }

            /** Close the socket connection. */
            connection.close();
            System.out.println(instr);
        }
        catch (IOException f) 
        {
            System.out.println("IOException: " + f);
        }
        catch (Exception g) 
        {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + g);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ***I have tried using a LONG, but the value I am trying to send is too large***

That's right. The value corresponds to

```
4225287479528688525220725405996728206163975
```

and the maximum value of a long is

```
9223372036854775807
```

You can store the number in a `BigInteger` as follows:

```
String process = "0x308101000c00234C51050000000099670007";
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(process.substring(2), 16);
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, whilst this helps in terms of being able to represent the BigInteger, it results in the OutputStreamWriter failing, as it is not applicable for the BigInteger argument. Is there an alternative that will allow me to buffer and then write the hex output, and then receive it in as well ? Thanks